# Best practice for layout templates in Meteor?

Tags: templates, meteor

Most templating systems I've used have a notion of a master "layout" template, and then a specialized content template for the specifics of the page. In expressjs, for example, there is quite literally a layout template separate from content (iirc works the same with either ejs or jade templates).

What do experienced Meteor developers do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options.

1) Use [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) in dev version. It's still being worked on, but as far as I know the layouts are already implemented and are great.

2) Wait until 0.6.0 version of Iron Router is stable and released.

3) Wait until 0.6.0 is released, and in the meantime use old [Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) and duplicate its functionality for layouts. Here's how:

In `index.html`, use `{{layout}}` instead of `{{renderPage}}`

```
<head>...</head>
<body>
  {{layout}}
</body>
```

Now define the global layout helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('layout', function(){
  if (Template[Session.get('layout')])
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('layout')]());
});
```

And set up a session variable in each route:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/news': function() {
    Session.set('layout', 'classicLayout');
    return 'news';
  },
});
```

And finally, use `{{renderPage}}` in your layout templates:

```
<template name="classicLayout">
  <div>
    {{renderPage}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you! Until I'm ready to rewrite all my routing, I'll stick with your Router version, which is very similar (but better) to the hack I had implemented.